How can I automate this requirement in mql4
I just want to pick a candle date and backtest it for a number of trading days (or 3 months) in history. Same time every day with the amount of candles I choose.
int cnd[] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; // Candle 8 = Test candle

double  high0 = iHigh(NULL,0,cnd[0]);  double   high1 = iHigh(NULL,0,cnd[1]); double high2 =   iHigh(NULL,0,cnd[2]); double high3 = iHigh(NULL,0,cnd[3]);    double high4 = iHigh(NULL,0,  cnd[4]); double high5 = iHigh(NULL,0,  cnd[5]);double high6 = iHigh(NULL,0,cnd[6]);  double high7 =      iHigh(NULL,0,cnd[7]); double high8 = iHigh(NULL,0,cnd[8]);
double   low0 = iLow(NULL,0, cnd[0]);  double   low1 = iLow(NULL,0,cnd[1]); double    low2 =    iLow(NULL,0,cnd[2]); double low3 =   iLow(NULL,0,cnd[3]);     double low4 = iLow(NULL,0,   cnd[4]); double low5 = iLow(NULL,0,    cnd[5]);double low6 = iLow(NULL,0,   cnd[6]);  double low7 =       iLow(NULL,0,cnd[7]); double low8 = iLow(NULL,0,  cnd[8]);
datetime time8 = iTime(NULL,0,cnd[8]);

Alert("Time(8):  ",TimeToString(time8)); // Test candle first
Alert("Points Above: (1) ",DoubleToString(low8-low7,1),"  (2) ",  DoubleToString(low8-low6,1),"  (3) ",   DoubleToString(low8-low5,1),"  (4) ",  DoubleToString(low8-low4,1),"  (5) ",  DoubleToString(low8-low3,1),"  (6) ",  DoubleToString(low8-low2,1),"  (7) ",  DoubleToString(low8-low1,1),"  (8) ",  DoubleToString(low8-low0,1));// Test candle first
Alert("Points Below: (1) ",DoubleToString(high7-high8,1),"  (2) ",DoubleToString(high6-high8,1),"  (3) ",DoubleToString(high5-high8,1),"  (4) ",DoubleToString(high4-high8,1),"  (5) ",DoubleToString(high3-high8,1),"  (6) ",DoubleToString(high2-high8,1),"  (7) ",DoubleToString(high1-high8,1),"  (8) ",DoubleToString(high0-high8,1)); //Test candle last
Alert("Range: ",DoubleToString(high8-low8,1),"    High: ",high8,"    Low: ",low8);     

My mechanical process is extremely large and lengthy. This is a small example.
